# ¿Como eliminar un objeto de una colección User Control creando un evento en el propio objeto?

Tags: c#, xaml

Supongamos que creo dinamicamente una coleccion de `User Control` dentro de un `StackPanel` de la siguiente manera;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            spVariables.Children.Add(new Tipo());
        }
```

La calse `Tipo` es una vista que tiene varios controles, uno de ellos es un botón con el cual quiero eliminar el propio objeto en cuestión, es decir, una vez tengo creados las 100 vistas, una encima de otra, me gustaria poder eliminar la que quiera si pulso el botón asociado a dicho objeto.

Veo que utilizando, por ejemplo;

```
        spVariables.Children.RemoveAt(2);
```

elimino perfectamente el objeto que esta en el `indice 2` de la colección, pero no se como hacer para que sea el botón propio del objeto quien sea el que se elimine a si mismo (dicho de una manera coloquial y nada profesional, pero me queda mas claro el explicarlo así...)

Espero me echéis una mano porque no logro encontrar una buena solución y dicho sea de paso, es un problema que suelo tener frecuentemente cuando tengo que compartir datos entre objetos situados en diferentes clases.

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es que en el boton se dispare un evento que te devuelva en el `sender` la referencia a tu `UserControl` para que lo puedas remover de tu StackPanel para esto puedes hacer una especie de *bypass* entre el evento del boton y un handler declarado en tu UserControl.

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private StackPanel StackPanelMain;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StackPanelMain = new StackPanel();

            var nControls = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < nControls; i++)
            {
                var megaUserControl = new MegaUserControl();
                megaUserControl.OnclickBtnDelete += MegaUserControl_OnclickBtnDelete;
                StackPanelMain.Children.Add(megaUserControl);
            }

            Content = StackPanelMain;
        }

        private void MegaUserControl_OnclickBtnDelete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var megaUserControl = sender as MegaUserControl;
            StackPanelMain.Children.Remove(megaUserControl);
        }

    }
```

La clase del UserControl:

```
public class MegaUserControl : UserControl
{
    private Button ButtonDelete;
    private event RoutedEventHandler _onclickBtnDelete;
    public event RoutedEventHandler OnclickBtnDelete
    {
        add { _onclickBtnDelete += value; }
        remove { _onclickBtnDelete -= value; }
    }
    public MegaUserControl()
    {
        ButtonDelete = new Button();
        ButtonDelete.Content = "Delete Item";
        //Aqui es donde this es la instancia del User control
        ButtonDelete.Click += (s, e) => _onclickBtnDelete?.Invoke(this, e);

        var stackPanelConten = new StackPanel();
        stackPanelConten.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        var labelDescription = new Label();
        labelDescription.Content = "Description de mi UC";

        //Agragando n elementos
        stackPanelConten.Children.Add(labelDescription);
        stackPanelConten.Children.Add(ButtonDelete);
        Content = stackPanelConten;
    }

}
```

Espero te Sirva saludos!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elcainas, tu ejemplo me ha sido de mucha ayuda.